# Associated type family fails, works when made standalone

Tags: haskell, type-families, associated-types

When I have code like the following:

```
class C where
  type T t1 t2
  ...

instance C (X t) where
  type T (X t) (t a b) = a
  ...
```

I get the error (with GHC head):

```
• Polymorphic type indexes of associated type ‘T’
    (i.e. ones independent of the class type variables)
    must be distinct type variables
```

Presumably this is because `(t a b)` is not a simple variable like the error implies it should be.

But I can simply reorganise the code like the following:

```
type family T t1 t2

class C where
  ...

type instance T (X t) (t a b) = a

instance C (X t) where
  ....
```

And then everything seems to work fine now.

Because a slightly messier syntax, do I lose anything by taking type family definitions out of classes, or are in-class definitions just syntactic sugar so taking them out is a relatively cost free workaround?

Comment: What are the parameters for `class C` ? I think that might be important.

Comment: My understanding is that at present, associated type families are pretty much syntactic sugar. I'm not really convinced they should have been added as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
type family T t1 t2
type instance T (X t) (t a b) = a
```

roughly works like this

```
class K t1 t1 where
   type T t1 t2
instance K (X t) (t a b) where
   type T (X t) (t a b) = a
```

Note how all the variables `t1,t2` are parameters of class `K`.
Indeed, this is required when variables occur more than once (i.e. non-linearly), as the posted error states:

```
• Polymorphic type indexes of associated type ‘T’
    (i.e. ones independent of the class type variables)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    must be distinct type variables
```

So, either you add all these type variables to your class, or - to the same effect - you move the type family outside the class.

---

This compiles in GHC 8.0.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, PolyKinds #-}

data X (t :: k) = X

class C t1 where
  type T t1 t2

instance C (X (t :: * -> * -> *)) where
  type T (X t) (t a b) = a
```